# How to mute jslint error on do{}while(false)

Tags: jslint

In this simple code:

```
do {
  console.log('o');
} while (false);
```

jslint produces a warning on the last line saying `Unexpected 'false'`

I understand why, but I still want to mute it because in these cases that's how I want to have the control flow.

Comment: jslint doesn't like `continue` either, but that's not stopping you either.

Comment: @JoeFrambach I can mute that with `/*jslint continue: true*/`

Comment: Interestingly, jslint allows `true` in `while(){}` and `for()` as an exception, but otherwise expects an explicit condition there. I'm gonna submit a patch to allow 'false' for `do{}while()` as another exception.

Comment: I don't know that `continue;` works the way you expect it to.  ;^)  Or I'm missing something. What would you add to your code to make it loop again?

Comment: @ruffin I won't make it loop in this case. The `do{}while(false)` is usually intended to provide a quick "exit" before some event that requires a lot of checks, avoiding nested ifs.

Comment: Sounds like you need a separate validation method. A "unit" with tests for such a unit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at what jslint *expects* in the while statement. From the source:

```
labeled_stmt('while', function () {
    one_space();
    var paren = next_token;
    funct.loopage += 1;
    advance('(');
    step_in('control');
    no_space();
    edge();
    this.arity = 'statement';
    this.first = expected_relation(expression(0));
    if (this.first.id !== 'true') {
        expected_condition(this.first, 'unexpected_a');
    }
    no_space();
    step_out(')', paren);
    one_space();
    this.block = block('while');
    if (this.block.disrupt) {
        prev_token.warn('strange_loop');
    }
    funct.loopage -= 1;
    return this;
});
```

It mostly reads like English. 'while', one space, (, no space, expected expression, no space, ).

So let's look at what an `expression(0)` is. You can read through the source if you're really interested, but to be honest I can't really wrap my head around it either. Sorry. https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint/blob/master/jslint.js

As far as I can tell, though, `expression(0)` traverses the tree of operators and operands, and looks for values with a Right Binding Power greater than 0? And `false` has a binding power of 0? But variables and comparisons are okay here. I have no clue how that even works. Ask Crockford.

As for shutting up jslint, here is my suggestion:

```
/*jslint devel: true, continue: true */
var i = 0;
var forever = false;
do {
    i = i + 1;
    if (i < 5) {
        continue;
    }
    console.log('o');
} while (forever);
```

Comment: It's `do`, not `while`. `epxression(0)` returns expression tree (constant in this case). It's the `expected_condition()` that throws that warning. It clearly does on any constant, that's just how jslint is. Thanks for the suggestion.